# How to use ElasticsearchEntityMapper if entity index is time based?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

As we know, every entity of ElasticsearchEntityMapper requires annotation

```
@Document(indexName="foo")
public class Foo {...}
```

, so that we can use convenient methods, like:

```
<T> Page<T> queryForPage(SearchQuery query, Foo.class);
```

But it is very common, that the indices of elasticsearch were designed time-based or language-based. i.e.

```
@Document(indexName="2019")
public class Foo {...}

@Document(indexName="2020")
public class Foo {...}
```

or

```
@Document(indexName="english")
public class Foo {...}

@Document(indexName="german")
public class Foo {...}
```

Of course, we can't create classes like this, **one class with different indices**. 
What should we do in this case? One class each index, Foo2019, Foo2020? <- Very bad idea.

I am wondering, why does spring-data-elasticsearch design entity in this way? It's not really flexible. Or I misunderstand the usage?

Thanks for your help in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are right in that using this with fix Strings is not flexible.

But you can also use a SpEL Expression for the index name. And when using the `ElasticsearchOperations` methods and not the repository methods, you can pass in the name of the index, this is overriding the name defined in the `@Document`annotation.